# Asp.Net Core 3.1 server starts and then stops immediately - Why?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

This is a simple repro of a problem that I'm having in a larger project. I started with a basic .Net Core 3.1 CLI App and I'm just trying to start a web server listening on localhost:42420.

Here's the output and as you can see it starts and then immediately shuts down. Why? What do I have to add to the configuration make it keep running?

```
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:42420
infoWeb server stopped.
: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Development
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: C:\Users\skrym\source\repos\wstest\wstest\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application is shutting down...
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Waiting for the host to be disposed. Ensure all 'IHost' instances are wrapped in 'using' blocks.
```

Note: I intentionally did not dispose the host so that I can see the extra log messages.

This is my project file:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

This is all the code:

```cs
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace wstest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Don't dispose this so we get all the log messages
            var host = CreateHost();
            host.Start();
            Console.WriteLine($"Web server stopped.");
        }

        private static IHost CreateHost()
        {
            var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
                .UseConsoleLifetime()
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(x => ConfigureWebHostBuilder(x));
            return host.Build();
        }

        private static IWebHostBuilder ConfigureWebHostBuilder(IWebHostBuilder builder)
        {
            return builder.UseStartup<SimpleStartup>()
                .UseUrls("http://localhost:42420")
                .UseContentRoot(AppContext.BaseDirectory);
        }
    }

    class SimpleStartup
    {
        public void Configure()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is with `host.Start();`. If you want the host to block until shut down, you need to use `host.Run();`.

Per the doc for [IHost](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.ihost?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1%5D):

> Start: Starts the host synchronously.

> Run: Runs an application and block the calling thread until host shutdown.

Comment: I had tried Run() previously in my other project and it was doing the same thing. You're right in this simpler repro Run works.